# JS: Regex in replace

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

i need this in php to javascript.

```
echo preg_replace('/(\S)+\?/', '', 'http://example.com/?test=1');
```

THX

BTW: I tried

```
alert('http://example.com/?test=1'.replace('/(\S)+\?/g', ''));
```

but no happens.

Comment: You should approve one of the given answers as an "Accepted answer", if your problem got solved (by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer. This lets other people know that you have received a good answer to your question. )

Answer (score 2):

Remove quotes from your RegExp:

```
alert('http://example.com/?test=1'.replace(/(\S)+\?/g, ''));
```

If you have quotes there, then it's trying to replace the string '/(\S)+\?/g' with '', and therefore not doing regular expression replace.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a regular expression object:

```
alert('http://example.com/?test=1'.replace(/(\S)+\?/g, ''));
```